# A way of removing the YouTube comment system?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, youtube

I find myself wasting time commenting on YouTube or replying to other peoples comments. I've tried to stop doing this but when I watch a video I compulsively scroll down to the comments almost straight away!

I'd like to know if there is any kind of script or add-on that you know about which will simply remove the comment system from my browser so I only get videos and the related video sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extension for Chrome called '[Youtube Options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-options/bdokagampppgbnjfdlkfpphniapiiifn?hl=en)'.

It doesn't only hide the commenting system but it also disables

1. intrusive youtube ads.
2. Sidebar videos.
3. Video suggestions.

I believe similar addons canbe found for mozilla firefox and other browsers.